# jQuery.reel plugin event for when images are loaded

Tags: jquery

The jquery.reel plugin caches all images...is there a way to tell when all the images have been loaded? and when using realtime images switching - when a new set of images have been loaded?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "loaded" event just for this. Example:

```
$("#image").bind("loaded", function(ev){
     alert('all images loaded');
 })
```